# I want to create a last clock filter pymongo

Tags: python, mongodb, flask, time, filter

I'm making a website. I write the all data I get from the database as a list. I want to make a filter. I just want to get the data in the last hour.

```
@app.route('/task/list/birsaat', methods=['GET'])
def get_birsaat():
  birsaat_tasks=tasks_collection.find({"zaman":"zaman.utcnow()-timedelta(hours=1)"})
  task_list_birsaat = []
  for rss_collection in birsaat_tasks:
      task_list_birsaat.append({'baslik': rss_collection['baslik'],
      'kisa_bilgi': rss_collection['kisa_bilgi'], 'link': rss_collection['link'],
      'zaman':    rss_collection['zaman'], 'saglayici': rss_collection['saglayici']})

  response_birsaat = jsonify(task_list_birsaat)
  response_birsaat.headers.add('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*')
  return response_birsaat
```

zaman means time in turkish. my database datas

```
_id:5eff873b4f9b5e349c14bc91
baslik:"KKTC’ye gelen tüm yolculara 1 gün karantina şartı getirildi"
kisa_bilgi:"haberler"
zaman:"Fri, 03 Jul 2020 21:25:00 +0300"
saglayici:"sabah"
```

Comment: `zaman` type is string or datetime in your database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IF you want to find the last hour result until now, you should add `$gte` in your query, and if the `zaman` is string you should convert your target value to the format you saved, if you want to access the `Fri, 03 Jul 2020 21:25:00 +0300` you can use this:

```
(zaman.utcnow()-timedelta(hours=1)).ctime())
```

the output is:

```
'Sat Jul  4 06:39:30 2020'
```

for adding the `,` to the above result you can use this:

```
dt = (zaman.utcnow()-timedelta(hours=1)).ctime()) 
spl = dt.split(' ')
res = spl[0] + ',' + ' ' + spl[3]  + spl[2] + ' ' + spl[-1] + ' ' + spl[4] + ' ' + '+0300'
```

the result is:
`'Sat, 4 2020 06:39:30 +0300'` 
then you should filter mongodb by this value.